# Importance of fluid mechanics and mechanics in physics and pipes

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

How does mechanics help prevent the pipes from bursting?
How does it link to the pressure of a pipe?
How does fluid mechanics link to physics when its about the liquid phase of chemical processes?

Comment: You have many questions, and those questions are VERY "open ended".  Please be more specific.

Comment: Have you heard of Hoop stress etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solid mechanics (mechanics of materials aka strength of materials) enables us to determine the state of strain and stress in the pipe, given the geometry and inside/outside pressures.  From this we can determine the pressure at which the pipe fails.

Fluid mechanics enables us to determine the pressure variations inside the pipe, given the fluid flow rate, density, and viscosity.